# Доступ к файловой системе windows server вне локальной сети

Tags: windows, сервер, сеть, windows-server

Здравствуйте. Используем windows server 2003 и 2008. На некоторых машинах, непонятно почему, нету доступа к файловой системе при обращении к ней через OVPN. Из локальной же сети подобных проблем не замечал. Пишет, если не ошибаюсь, невозможно подключится, ping же проходит, подключение через RDC тоже. Для доступа к некоторым машинам срабатывало (Windows 7 и >) добавление пользователя и пароля для этого адреса в диспетчере учётных данных, ну с этим всё понятно, возможно необходимо в сетевых настройках машины указать доступ без пароля.

Как правильно настроить такой доступ? Какие настройки на это влияют?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте просмотреть трафик на обоих концах во время попытки открыть сетевую папку с проблемной машины. Обычно это проясняет ситуацию.
Также стоит помнить, что протокол SMB 1.x, используемый в WinXP, совершенно не дружит с маршрутизацией, так что если проблемы возникают именно с машинами на XP, стоит искать решение в этой области.